# What is the command line to install mongodb?

Tags: software-installation, mongodb

I am trying to install MongoDB, but I keep getting the following error:

```
mongodb is not found.
```

I am using the following install command:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 12.04? Mongodb is a package in Ubuntu 12.10, not 12.04: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mongodb&searchon=names&suite=quantal&section=all

Comment: Follow the proper instructions mentioned at [docs.mongodb.org](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). Seems like you have skipped added/updated source.

Comment: i am new in linux how to add this package in my system

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot install mongodb using:

```
apt-get install mongo
```

You need to execute following command to install mongodb on linux:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-server
```

Comment: Returns `E: Package 'mongodb-server' has no installation candidate` on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

To install mongodb run the commands:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

To test connection (wait at least 15 seconds to let the db start up), run the command below.

```
mongo
```

If the command exits with a error about not being able to connect, then reboot, and log back in as the admin user.

Sometimes MongoDB fails to create a network socket when it is started immediately after installation. It should automatically start

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to install mongodb in Ubuntu 12.x :-

1. Use the Ubuntu Software installation center. In search type mongodb

   You will see *Object/document-oriented database (metapackage) mongdb* - install that.
2. Download the mongodb from http://www.mongodb.org/downloads  according to you OS and supported 32/64 bit version and follow [this guide on Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-12-04)

   If there is a `.deb` package available then download it and directly install by double clicking.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu precise/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org=3.6.0 mongodb-org-server=3.6.0 mongodb-org-shell=3.6.0 mongodb-org-mongos=3.6.0 mongodb-org-tools=3.6.0
```